# Generate Target in Makefile from a variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my source code directory, there are files named **man_en**, **man_de**.
Now I wish to have targets provided for each of them like:
**/usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz** and
**/usr/share/man/de/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz**, for rules like:

```
/usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz: man_en  
     gzip -c man_en > /usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz
/usr/share/man/de/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz: man_de  
     gzip -c man_de > /usr/share/man/de/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz
```

If somebody adds a file **man_fr** to the source code directory, the target
**/usr/share/man/fr/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz**
should be generated or provided automatically.
Can I achieve this without a program that modifies my Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is just an application for an [implicit pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html),
but it's slightly complicated by the fact that `man_en` is an exception to the
general pattern rule that yields the target name. Here's an example solution:

**Makefile**

```
PROGRAM ?= prog

FOREIGN_MAN_SRCS := $(subst man_en,,$(wildcard man_*))
FOREIGN_MAN_TARGS := $(patsubst man_%,/usr/share/man/%/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz,$(FOREIGN_MAN_SRCS))
EN_MAN_TARG := /usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz

.PHONY: all

all: $(FOREIGN_MAN_TARGS) $(EN_MAN_TARG)

/usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz: man_en  
    gzip -c man_en > /usr/share/man/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz

/usr/share/man/%/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz: man_%  
    gzip -c man_$* > /usr/share/man/$*/man1/$(PROGRAM).1.gz
```

which will run like:

```
$ make --dry-run
gzip -c man_de > /usr/share/man/de/man1/prog.1.gz
gzip -c man_fr > /usr/share/man/fr/man1/prog.1.gz
gzip -c man_en > /usr/share/man/man1/prog.1.gz
```

I recommend the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: Thany You! I thought, there might be some possibility to place a variable name like $(SUBDIR) into the target name e.g. by a define ... endef command, but this seems not to be the case and Your solution worked.

Comment: @GeraldSchade You're welcome. For saying "Thanks" on SO, pelase see Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)